# Flex-box not working in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

This is SO frustrating. I have tried dozens of "fixes" I am hoping someone can help.  I have a flexbox that works well in Chrome and IE, but not Safari (iOS and desktop).

The CSS:

```
.resulist40 {
    list-style: none;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    float:clear;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 350px;
    width: initial;

}
.reslist40 {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        -ms-flex: 1;
            flex: 1;
    min-height: 34px;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<ul class="resulist40">
            <li class="reslist40">
               <a onclick="dovid(1);">Day 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="reslist40">
            </li>...
</ul>
```

Here is the desired look (from CHROME):
[image]

Here is what it looks like in Safari:

[image]

Comment: Down vote, but no comments? What did I not supply?

Answer (score 1):

This is my fix, I am not 100% happy. It seems that Safari dosen't work well without having a fixed width -  so the flexbox is not really responsive. I found that a width of 130px gives me 3 cols on all browsers.

```
.resulist40 {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: row;
            flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 10px;
 }
 .reslist40 {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 130px;
    height: 34px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't mind me as I dig up this post. 
 I had a similar
misfortune recently but in my case I had...

```
img {
   height: auto;
   width: 100%;
}
```

and Safari was not having it. So I changed it to...

```
img {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}
```

which made Safari happy again.